# When to use "Tree view" or when to use "Managed navigation" , if i want to be able to filter my pages using term store

Tags: 2013, navigation, managed-metadata, term-store, site-settings

Seems there are two main approaches if I want to be able to filter my wiki pages using metadata term store inside enterprise wiki site collection.

First Approach. Tree View Approach is to do the following:-

- Enable the “Metadata Navigation and Filtering” site feature inside my site collection.
- Go to “Site Setting >> Tree View >> enable tree view”
- Got to “Library settings >>  Metadata Navigation Settings”, configure the fields to be displayed.
- The result is that I will get all the current term store fields inside a tree as follow:-

  [image]

Second Approach. Managed Navigation Approach is to do the following:-

- Go to Site Setting>> Navigation.
- Chose Managed Navigation under the Global navigation,
- Chose the wiki category , from the term store.
- The result will be that I will get managed navigation at the top;

[image]

Now i am not sure which approach is the correct one to follow & what are the differences between the two approaches?

From my side I find the following differences:-

- Using tree view is more user friendly and will allow having extra columns inside the tree, this can be controlled using " Metadata Navigation Settings" under the library settings.
- While using the managed navigation , I can only chose to have one term set such as the default wiki category. And the look and feel is not very user friendly

Now as I mentioned before the idea is that I want the ability to click on a term and get all the wiki pages that have been tagged using this term.
Although both solutions will not allow metadata filtering to be done  out of the box, for example using tree view I have to deploy the following solution to enable this ([link](https://markuspersson.wordpress.com/2012/01/19/add-metadata-navigation-on-custom-page-layouts/)), otherwise clicking on any term inside the Tree view will just redirect to the home page.. while for the managed navigation I did not use this before..

```
public class CustomWikiPageBase : PublishingLayoutPage
{
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["TreeField"]) 
            && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["TreeValue"]))
        {
            Response.Redirect(String.Format("{0}?TreeField={1}&TreeValue={2}",
                SPContext.Current.ListItem.ParentList.DefaultViewUrl,
                Request.QueryString["TreeField"],
                Request.QueryString["TreeValue"]));
        }
        else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["TreeField"]))
        {
            Response.Redirect(String.Format("{0}?TreeField={1}",
                SPContext.Current.ListItem.ParentList.DefaultViewUrl,
                Request.QueryString["TreeField"]));
        }
        base.OnInit(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John,

All of the examples I've found online tell you to use the Managed Navigation approach.

I found a video tutorial and step-by-step instructions that are quite similar.

[Managed Metadata Navigation in SharePoint 2013](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ICmKCSGS7M) 
[SharePoint 2013 – Navigation using Managed Metadata (Term Store)](http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2012/07/20/sharepoint-2013-navigation-using-managed-metadata-term-store-aspx/)

Comment: but what is the problem if i use Tree view instead as it will allow me to have more than one term set inside the navigation tree,, while using managed navigation will only allow me to show one term set , which is "thing to know" in your  example that you provide a link for...

Comment: That's is a noted limitation I'm afraid. 

"Limitation # 1 => 1:1 Relationship between Site Collection and Term Set" http://nikpatel.net/2014/06/09/limitations-of-managed-navigation-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: so you mean using a Tree view as described on this link https://markuspersson.wordpress.com/2012/01/19/add-metadata-navigation-on-custom-page-layouts/ might be a better approach to follow ??

Comment: It would appear so as you can't have more than one term set per site navigation. Did it give you the desired results though? Any drawbacks?

Comment: you know in SharePoint using the correct approach is the first step to follow, which i am currently trying to accomplish ..  now i have a feeling that both solutions are intended for different purposes. Because managed navigation is not designed to allow metadata filtering, but it is designed to allow having a global navigation so each term inside the managed navigation will be manually linked to a page, while using tree view is intended to allow users to click on certain term and get all the pages that have this term inside it ... what do u think ?

Comment: Correct. I also found a JavaScript solution you may want to consider. https://habaneroconsulting.com/insights/returning-a-sharepoint-2013-termset-in-a-tree-structure-using-javascript#.VYweOkb5FK4

Comment: but what is the purpose of the javascript you mentioned ?  i did not understand how/why to use it ?

Comment: It works similar to the link you posted. I didn't research it much, but it would be something more flexible to use with SharePoint online.

Comment: i read more about these approaches and from what i find is that having a managed navigation is different than enabling managed metadata and filtering. where in the managed navigation, the term store will mainly contain terms referring to single pages such as contect us, about us, read more , etc... those terms are not tags inside the wiki pages ,, unlike using the metadata tree which is mainly use to allow manged metadata filtering,, what do u think ?

Comment: Sounds dead on. I think you're wanting to go the metadata route, so you can filter the content. You could do both actually. They're mutually exclusive.

Comment: Just to clarify...use the term store / managed navigation to get the friendly URLs. Users can use that to find pages where they already know where to find the content they want. Use the metadata tree for more granular filtering of content.

Comment: but in the managed metadata tree you create TermSets and then you define managed metadata columns, so in this case the same term can be found in more than one page. let say a i create a termset named "Departments", and i define all the departments as terms. So the same term for example HR will be found on many wiki pages, and when you click on the HR term all the related pages will be filtered. unlike using this in the managed navigation,, where the term HR will be linked to a single page, so i think both are used differently one for metadata filtering the other to define navigation

Comment: John...check out this article. This looks like this might help. http://blogs.interfacett.com/how-to-apply-metadata-navigation-filtering-in-sharepoint-2013